# How to define chamfered rectangle as .pic in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to generate a diagram which repeatedly contains the same graphics. See below a sample graphics:

[image]

This is how I am generating it:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2px]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    line/.style={-, draw=black!30, line width=1pt},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node[draw=black!30, rectangle, minimum height=8mm, minimum width=8mm,line width=1pt, chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle corners={south west, south east},chamfered rectangle xsep=2pt, below] at (0, 0) (b1) {} ;
    \node[draw=black!30, rectangle, minimum height=8mm, minimum width=8mm,line width=1pt, chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle corners={south west, south east},chamfered rectangle xsep=2pt, below] at (1, 1) (b2) {} ;
    \node[draw=black!30, rectangle, minimum height=8mm, minimum width=8mm,line width=1pt, chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle corners={south west, south east},chamfered rectangle xsep=2pt, below] at (0, 2) (b3) {} ;
    \draw[line] (b1) -- (b2) -- (b3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I wish to define the chamfered rectangle as a .pic so that it can be used later on with `\path` command.

I am looking for something like this:

```
\tikzset{
line/.style={-, draw=black!30, line width=1pt},
box/.pic={
    \draw[draw=black!30, rectangle, minimum height=8mm, minimum width=8mm,line width=1pt, chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle corners={south west, south east},chamfered rectangle xsep=2pt, below] (0, 0);
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \path[line] (0, 0) pic {box} --
                (1, 1) pic {box} --
                (0, 2) pic {box};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can use nodes in a path command.

Comment: @marmot: yes, I can. However I am learning `pic` at this moment, hence I am asking to define a `pic` to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2px]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    line/.style={-, draw=black!30, line width=1pt},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mycham/.style={draw=black!30, rectangle, minimum height=8mm,
minimum width=8mm,line width=1pt, chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle
corners={south west, south east},chamfered rectangle
xsep=2pt},pics/champic/.style={code={\node[mycham] (-node){};}}]
    \path (0, 0) pic (b1) {champic}
    -- (1, 1) pic (b2){champic} 
    -- (0,2)  pic (b3){champic};
    \draw[line] (b1-node) -- (b2-node) -- (b3-node);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could define the `pic` *in this case* also using `pics/champic/.style={code={\node[mycham] (-node){};}}`. However, AFAIK, this syntax is less flexible. Imagine you want to pass more than one arguments to the pic, as in

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2px]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    line/.style={-, draw=black!30, line width=1pt},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mycham/.style={draw=black!30, rectangle, minimum height=8mm,
minimum width=8mm,line width=1pt, chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle
corners={south west, south east},chamfered rectangle
xsep=2pt},pics/champic/.style n args={2}{code={\node[mycham,#2] (-node){#1};}}]
    \path (0, 0) pic (b1) {champic={A}{blue}}
    -- (1, 1) pic (b2){champic={B}{red}} 
    -- (0,2)  pic (b3){champic={C}{green!70!black}};
    \draw[line] (b1-node) -- (b2-node) -- (b3-node);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, with the syntax chosen here this is no problem, but with the `/.pic=` syntax I wouldn't know how to do that.

Of course, if you have no parameters, and are sure you never need some, you can do

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2px]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    line/.style={-, draw=black!30, line width=1pt},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mycham/.style={draw=black!30, rectangle, minimum height=8mm,
minimum width=8mm,line width=1pt, chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle
corners={south west, south east},chamfered rectangle
xsep=2pt},champic/.pic={\draw (0,0) node[mycham] (-node){};}]
    \path (0, 0) pic (b1) {champic}
    -- (1, 1) pic (b2){champic} 
    -- (0,2)  pic (b3){champic};
    \draw[line] (b1-node) -- (b2-node) -- (b3-node);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks, marmot. This is a cool way to define a `pic` where you have used `node`. I wasn't aware of this way. I just added a preferred way of defining the `pic` in the question, since I can see a similar way inside [tikz documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) as well. Can you please have a look and update the answer accordingly?

Comment: @RaviJoshi Actually I believe that the way I use is advantageous as it allows you to define `pic`s that take more than one arguments. If you want the other syntax, you could use `,champic/.pic={\node[mycham] (-node){};}` instead of `,pics/champic/.style={code={\node[mycham] (-node){};}}` but I wouldn't. Please notice also that there seems to exist a bug if you nest `pic`s (which we are not doing here).

Comment: (1) As per `tikz documentation` at page 262 Section 18.3, `pics/seagull/.style ={code = {\draw (...) ...;}}` and `seagull/.pic = {\draw (...) ...;}` are same. Hence I guess `champic/.pic={\node[mycham] (-node){};}` and `pics/champic/.style={code={\node[mycham] (-node){};}}` are same. (2) Page 259 of the same manual defines a `pic` using `my pic/.pic = {\draw (-3mm,-3mm) rectangle (3mm,3mm);}`. Hence may I use `box/.pic = {\draw (0, 0) rectangle[chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle corners={south west, south east},chamfered rectangle xsep=2pt, below] (8mm, 8mm);}` to define the `pic`?

Comment: I am so sorry for multiple questions asked above. Can you please answer them as it will clearify my doubts related to `pic`?

Comment: @RaviJoshi I added an explanation for why I prefer the syntax I use. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah! Since you used a `node` to define a `pic`, you can change the parameters of the `node` from the `pic`, which is wonderful! At present, I don’t need to change any parameters in the drawing. Hence, is it possible to define the `pic` using `box/.pic={\draw (0, 0) rectangle ... `; as mentioned in the point (2) of my question above?

Comment: @RaviJoshi Done. (Of course with `\draw (0, 0) node ...` instead of `\draw (0, 0) rectangle `. Or do you want to avoid using a node?)

Comment: Perfect!!! Either way is fine. I guess if a node (with rectangle) is not used then we have to manually define all points of the chamfered rectangle with `cycle`.

Comment: @RaviJoshi Yes. You could do that. However, I do not see the point of it if you are happy with the `chamfered rectangles`.

Comment: Completely agree with you. Thank you very much.